# Converting React Class component to Function Component With Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to convert the class component in my react app below :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactTable from 'react-table'
import api from '../api'

import styled from 'styled-components'

import 'react-table/react-table.css'

const Wrapper = styled.div`
    padding: 0 40px 40px 40px;
`

const Update = styled.div`  
    color: #ef9b0f;
    cursor: pointer;
`

const Delete = styled.div`
    color: #ff0000;
    cursor: pointer;
`

class UpdateVoter extends Component {
    updateUser = event => {
        event.preventDefault()

        window.location.href = `/voters/update/${this.props.id}`
    }

    render() {
        return <Update onClick={this.updateUser}>Update</Update>
    }
}

class DeleteVoter extends Component {
    deleteUser = event => {
        event.preventDefault()

        if (
            window.confirm(
                `Do you want to delete this voter ${this.props.id} permanently?`,
            )
        ) {
            api.deleteVoterById(this.props.id)
            window.location.reload()
        }
    }

    render() {
        return <Delete onClick={this.deleteUser}>Delete</Delete>
    }
}

class VotersList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            voters: [],
            columns: [],
            isLoading: false,
        }
    }

    componentDidMount = async () => {
        this.setState({ isLoading: true })

        await api.getAllVoters().then(voters => {
            this.setState({
                voters: voters.data.data,
                isLoading: false,
            })
        })
    }

    render() {
        const { voters, isLoading } = this.state

        const columns = [
            {
                Header: 'ID',
                accessor: '_id',
                filterable: true,
            },
            {
                Header: 'No KK',
                accessor: 'nkk',
                filterable: true,
            },
            {
                Header: 'NIK',
                accessor: 'nik',
                filterable: true,
            },
            {
                Header: 'Nama',
                accessor: 'nama',
                filterable: true,
            },
            {
                Header: 'Alamat',
                accessor: 'alamat',
                filterable: true,
            },
            {
                Header: '',
                accessor: '',
                Cell: function(props) {
                    return (
                        <span>
                            <DeleteVoter id={props.original._id} />
                        </span>
                    )
                },
            },
            {
                Header: '',
                accessor: '',
                Cell: function(props) {
                    return (
                        <span>
                            <UpdateVoter id={props.original._id} />
                        </span>
                    )
                },
            },
        ]

        let showTable = true
        if (!voters.length) {
            showTable = false
        }

        return (
            <Wrapper>
                {showTable && (
                    <ReactTable
                        data={voters}
                        columns={columns}
                        loading={isLoading}
                        defaultPageSize={10}
                        showPageSizeOptions={true}
                        minRows={0}
                    />
                )}
            </Wrapper>
        )
    }
}

export default VotersList
```

to the functional component with hooks, like this :

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import ReactTable from 'react-table'
import api from '../api'

import styled from 'styled-components'

import 'react-table/react-table.css'

const Wrapper = styled.div`
    padding: 0 40px 40px 40px;
`

const Update = styled.div`
    color: #ef9b0f;
    cursor: pointer;
`

const Delete = styled.div`
    color: #ff0000;
    cursor: pointer;
`

function UpdateVoter(props) {
    const updateUser = event => {
        event.preventDefault()

        window.location.href = `/voters/update/${props.id}`
    }

    
        return <Update onClick={updateUser}>Update</Update>

}

function DeleteVoter(props) {
    const deleteUser = event => {
        event.preventDefault()

        if (
            window.confirm(
                `Do tou want to delete this voter ${props.id} permanently?`,
            )
        ) {
            api.deleteVoterById(props.id)
            window.location.reload()
        }
    }

    
        return <Delete onClick={deleteUser}>Delete</Delete>
  
}

function VotersListSpecific(props) {
    const [state, setState] = useState ({
            voters: [],
            columns: [],
            isLoading: false,
        })
   

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            setState({ ...state, isLoading: true })

            let voters = await api.getAllVoters()
            setState({
                voters: voters.data.data, 
                ...state,
                isLoading: true,
            })
        }
        fetchData()
        console.log(fetc)
    }, [])

        const { voters, isLoading } = state

        const columns = [
            {
                Header: 'ID',
                accessor: '_id',
            },
            {
                Header: 'No KK',
                accessor: 'nkk',
            },
            {
                Header: 'NIK',
                accessor: 'nik',
            },
            {
                Header: 'Nama',
                accessor: 'nama',
            },
            {
                Header: 'Alamat',
                accessor: 'alamat',
            },
            {
                Header: '',
                accessor: '',
                Cell: function(props) {
                    return (
                        <span>
                            <DeleteVoter id={props.original._id} />
                        </span>
                    )
                },
            },
            {
                Header: '',
                accessor: '',
                Cell: function(props) {
                    return (
                        <span>
                            <UpdateVoter id={props.original._id} />
                        </span>
                    )
                },
            },
        ]

        let showTable = true
        if (!voters.length) {
            showTable = false
        }

        return (
            <Wrapper>
                {showTable && (
                    <ReactTable
                        data={voters}
                        columns={columns}
                        loading={isLoading}
                        defaultPageSize={10}
                        showPageSizeOptions={true}
                        minRows={0}
                    />
                )}
            </Wrapper>
        )
    
}

export default VotersList
```

But, the code is not working. The table is not displayed. The "voters" array inside the state is empty. Besides that, I also got this warning :

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'state'. Either include
> it or remove the dependency array. You can also do a functional update
> 'setState(s => ...)' if you only need 'state' in the 'setState' call
> react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

I really need help to solve this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

### My Suggestion

First of all, `useState` is not like the `this.state` in class components. You are recommended to assign each primitive *state* with a `useState` function. For example, in you `VotersListSpecific` component, instead of having one state wrapping up `voters`, `columns` and `isLoading`, you could have:

```js
const [voters, setVoters] = useState([])
const [columns, setColumns] = useState([])
const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false)
```

Still it can be further optimized using `useReducer`, but it would be way too off-topic for now. You can checkout the [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html) if interested.

### Your Problem

Now let us analyze what you did right and what you did wrong.

#### The Rights

When you change the state, you use the syntax `setState({ ...state, isLoading: true })`, which is correct as React only toggles the re-render when the reference of the object is changed. If you use something like this:

```js
state.isLoading = false
setState(state)
```

The reference if the state is not changed in this case, so React will not re-render.

#### The Wrongs

When you call `const { voters, isLoading } = state`, the `voters` variable points to the `voters` field of the state, which is an empty array at the time of first render. Some time later, when the new `state` is created with the new `voters`, the new `state.voters` actually points to a new array. But React does not know about this change as you have explicitly pointed the `voter` variable to the original empty array, which is a field of the old `state`.

A fix to this would be something like:

```js
const [voters, setVoters] = useState([])
useEffect(async () => {
  setVoters(await api.getAllVoters())
}, [])
return (
  <ReactTable data={voters}/>
)
```

Another approach can be using `data={state.voters}`.

Comment: I'm sorry. What do you mean by "the new `state.voters` actually points to a new array"? What I understand is after the first render, state is changed by `useEffect` function, and trigger the second render, which fill the `voters` variable with the new state (state that contains data from `api.getAllVoters` function). Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: In you original post, you used `data={voters}` to pass the `voters`, an array, to the component props. But when you called `setState`, you are changing the `state` object, not the `voters` object. You can either use `data={state.voters}` to tell React to watch the change of `state` object, or better, assign `voters` using an individual `useState`, just like my example.

Comment: it seems the concept of reference vs value is confusing you here. There are dozens of materials online that explains this concept, a quick search gave me [this post](https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0) which seems helpful.

Comment: I have used `data={state.voters}`, but I still got the same result (the table is not displayed)

Comment: Hmm, I will check this approach again locally once I've got spare time. Have you tried another fix `const [voters, setVoters] = useState([])`?

Comment: Hi. I've tried that. Still the same result. Thank you for your sincerity

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to React Functional programming.

I don't have all your dependencies so I'm trying to answer your question by eye instead of actual compiling.

A grain of salt when updating state is, instead of doing this:

```
setState({
   ...state,
   ...yourstuffhere
})
```

do this:

```
setState(prevState => {
    return {
        ...prevState,
        ...yourstuffhere
    }
});
```

What happens is by doing above, you are making sure that you have updated data from previous state. Remember that `setState` is an async function. Unless you do it like that, you might accidentally lose some data on the fly.

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
        setState(prevState => { 
            return {
                ...prevState, isLoading: true 
            }
        })

        let voters = await api.getAllVoters()
        setState(prevState => {
            return {
                voters: voters.data.data, 
                ...prevState,
                isLoading: true,
            }
        })
    }
    fetchData()
    console.log(fetc)
}, [])
```

Comment: I've tried that. But I got this error :

(anonymous function)

`70 | let voters = api.getAllVoters()
71 |     setState((prevState) => {
72 |         return {
> 73 |             voters: voters.data.data, 
| ^  74 |             ...prevState,
75 |             isLoading: true
76 |         } `